# Trouble with text encoding using LWUIT Facebook API

Tags: facebook, lwuit

I've been working on a project using the LWUIT facebook API and it was really easy to process authentication and post to the user's wall through my JavaME application. However, I realized that the api was not encoding my messages correctly.

Looking into the code, I noticed that there are is a call to a Util.encodeUrl in the ConnectionRequest addArgument method to handle text encoding. However, line breaks and other special characters are still not rendered properly in my facebook posts.

Has anyone had the same or similar errors with this API? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Again, I found the answer to my technical challenges and would like to document it here so as to close the question and just in case someone else hits a similar road block.

It appears that facebook does not support formatting of wall posts when connecting through an app on the graph api. Therefore 
 tags, line break characters, etc will not be properly displayed. This would make sense as most wall posts are not meant to be lengthy prose.

However, if you really need to format a message, a facebook note would be your most favourable alternative as it supports HTML tags.